# How to remove characters before matching pattern and after matching pattern in R in one line?

Tags: r

I have this vector `Target <- c( "tes_1123_SS1G_340T01", "tes_23_SS2G_340T021"`. I want to remove anything before SS and anything after T0 (including T0).
Result I want in one line of code:

`SS1G_340` `SS2G_340`

Code I have tried:
`gsub("^.*?SS|\\T0", "", Target)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsub(".*(SS.*)T0.*","\\1",Target)

[1] "SS1G_340" "SS2G_340"
```

Why it works:

With regex, we can choose to keep a pattern and remove everything outside of that pattern with a two-step process. Step 1 is to put the pattern we'd like to keep in parentheses. Step 2 is to reference the number of the parentheses-bound pattern we'd like to keep, as sometimes we might have multiple parentheses-bound elements. See the example below for example:

```
gsub(".*(SS.*)+(T0.*)","\\1",Target)

[1] "SS1G_340" "SS2G_340"
```

Note that I've put the T0.* in parentheses this time, but we still get the correct answer because I've told gsub to return the first of the two parentheses-bound patterns. But now see what happens if I use \\2 instead:

```
gsub(".*(SS.*)+(T0.*)","\\2",Target)

[1] "T01"  "T021"
```

The .* are wild cards by the way. If you'd like to learn more about using regex in R, [here's a reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) that can get you started.

Comment: Could you please explain why you have `"\\1"`?

Comment: @MAPK - No problem. See the added explanation above.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(Target, "SS[^T]*")
#[1] "SS1G_340" "SS2G_340"
```

Comment: I haven't used str_extract much. Do you know about any speed differences between sub, gsub, and str_extract for large scale applications?

Comment: @RyanRunge  `str_extract` use `stringi` functions like `stri_extract` which is very fast.  So, it should be faster

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks, I'll have to try that next time.

Comment: stringr is built on top of stringi ,which uses ICU  C library ,should be faster than gsub